# Accidentally deleted the “cable” item “Setup > Network” in GNOME and can’t re-establish Internet connectivity

Tags: networking, gnome

Recently, I erased the "cable" item under “Setup > Network” in GNOME by mistake.

After doing this, I cannot connect to the Internet.

While cable connection is established with ease (automatically), using a web browser—for example—doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I checked `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` in network-scripts. It was `ifcfg-enp3s0` that should be set to`ifcfg-enp5s0`.

I changed `ifcfg-enp3s0` into `ifcfg-enp5s0` and now I can use the Internet without worrying.